# Needed to take the full path of the uploaded file from client Machine

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I just needed to take the full path of the uploaded file from client Machine.

I tried

```
strDir = Upload1.PostedFile.FileName

strDir = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Upload1.PostedFile.FileName)
```

with upload control, but it doesn't work that kind.

I too know that security concerns will not allow the server to be aware of the file path, but are there any other alternate options to retrieve the file path. If yes please reply to the post....

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, unless you create/register a protocol handler that can communicate with the OS, or perhaps create an ActiveX control (works only with IE) or a Java applet. Browsers don't natively communicate with the computer.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't waste your time.**

For security reasons browsers do no allow get client path, ie JavaScript in browser has no access to the File System, however using HTML5 File API, only Firefox provides a `mozFullPath` property, but fortunately if you try to get the value it returns an empty string: